# How do add the array values from mysql database?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add the product quantity  based on customer name.Here I fetch the values based on customer name and store into array ,now I want to add the quantity values.In select query ,the condition customer having 2+2= 4 qty in separate of two rows How can I add the qty values.

```
 $selectproduct = "SELECT * FROM purchase_item WHERE custname = '$customername'";  
 $resultselectproduct = $conn->query($selectproduct); 
 if ( $resultselectproduct ->num_rows >0 )
 {
     while($rowselectproduct = $resultselectproduct->fetch_assoc())
     { 
          $array[] = $rowselectproduct;
     }
}
```

My database structure:

```
custname  product  qty
 A          ProA    2
 A          ProB    2
```

When I run the query based on 'A' customer I got the value as qty value 4

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show us your desired output

Comment: Show your database structure

Comment: What kind of terrible database design identifies records by user _name_? This should be an id.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query and use the SUM() function.  Like so:

```
$query = "SELECT 

SUM(qty) AS total

FROM `purchase_item`

WHERE `custname` = '$customername'"; 

$stmt = $conn->query($query);

$result = $stmt->fetch_assoc();

echo $result['total'];
```

Comment: But i got the error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\onceagaincome.php on line 40